# chemmacros error but output ok

Tags: errors, chemmacros

Take the following simple piece of code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\ch{ HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A\mch}
\end{document}
```

It produces the correct output 
[image]

(ignore cropping marks at bottom and right!)

but spews up an error as such:

```
! Improper alphabetic constant.
<to be read again>
                   \__int_eval_end:
l.4 \ch{ HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A\mch}
                                   ^^M
A one-character control sequence belongs after a ` mark.
So I'm essentially inserting \0 here.
```

Although it does not affect the pdf output as such, it is a pain as the error keeps occurring and I have many of these `chemmacros`equations in use in my (much larger) work.

Can anyone explain where is this error coming from?

It only appeared today (8th Sept 2015) and was ok yesterday.

Comment: I get no error if I remove the leading space (before the first `H`).

Comment: I think it has to do with the last revision of `expl3`, since `chemmacros` itself has not changed.

Comment: Can we change `\mch` to `-` and `chemmacros` to `chemformula`? (Because a fix requires work in `chemformula` and not in `chemmacros`!)

Comment: I'll send a fixed version of `chemformula` to CTAN later today

Comment: I tried all combinations of the above comments but to no avail. Removing the leading space threw up more errors 'undefined control sequence...'. Changing 'chemmacros' to 'chemformula' and '\mch' to '-' gives same error as reported originally. I'll wait for fix in CTAN. Cheers.

Comment: »Changing 'chemmacros' to 'chemformula' and '\mch' to '-' gives same error as reported originally.« of course: that's the point! The issue has nothing to do with `chemmacros`.

Comment: »Removing the leading space threw up more errors 'undefined control
sequence...'« what kind of errors?

Comment: @clemens Do you know what's wrong here? I think I know which `expl3` commit broke things. (Or rather: is this an issue at your end or at ours?)

Comment: @clemens with the leading space removed and keeping `chemmacros` I get the following error: `! Undefined control sequence.
\l__chemformula_arrow_label_style_tl ...tnotesize
l.4 \ch{HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A\mch }The control sequence at the end of the top line of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type ` `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., ` `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.`

Comment: @JosephWright this reproduces the error: `\tl_set_rescan:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {} {}` (I should take care the argument isn't empty in the first place I guess…)

Comment: @clemens That looks like something we can/should fix ourselves: I'll log and look to push out a fix today.

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/266

Comment: @Leeser that's quite strange. Which version of `chemformula` are you using?

Comment: @clemens `chemformula v4.12a 2015/08/29` texmaker (latest version) Mac OS X TeXLive TLUtility daily updates...

Comment: @Leeser hmm, I'm out of ideas then: `\l__chemformula_arrow_label_style_tl` is defined in line 312 of v 4.12a. (besides the fact that it only is used when you have an arrow with captions)

Comment: @clemens have you been able to replicate the error? It only appeared yesterday, so something else may be causing the issue as I update all packages using TLutility daily.

Comment: @Leeser the one in the question: yes, the one in the comments: no.

Comment: @clemens problem seems to have disappeared...when I process the above code without the leading space before the H as in egreg's comment all is ok. i.e. `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\begin{document}
\ch{HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A\mch}
\end{document}  `However, if I change `chemmacros` to `chemformula` I get the error `! Undefined control sequence. \l__chemformula_arrow_label_style_tl ...tnotesize l.4 \ch{HA + H2O <=> H3O+ + A\mch }...` as in one of my above comments. So for the time being I can get away with it by using `chemmacros`. Is this because you fixed it yesterday?

Comment: Do we close this as off-topic? It should be solved on an up to date TL...

Comment: Well, it wasn't off-topic at the time. The update solved it! But for future searches it is no longer a relevant question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue described a temporary bug and is resolved through updating the TeX distribution.